# Bipartite graph and perfect matching proof

Tags: graph-theory

I have a problem with a bipartite graph and I need some help. We have the following idea: $G = (S,T;E)$ bipartite graph without isolated vertices where $|S| \ge |T|$ and for each edge $st \in E\ (s \in S,\  t \in T)$ we have the following inequality $d_G(s)\ge d_G(t)$.

The first problem: Show that $|S| = |T|$ and each connected component of $G$ is a regular bipartite graph.

The second problem: Show that the graph $G$ has a perfect matching.

Comment: Please share your efforts so that someone can guide further

Comment: I dont understand the problem very well... i would like someone to help me...

Comment: I edited your question to improve the English. Please correct my edit if I have changed the meaning.

Comment: These are fairly standard theorems which you would find in any good graph theory textbook.  I suggest either you tell us your proof attempts so that we can assist, or that you try to understand the standard proofs and let us know if you have questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first part, count the number of elements of $S$ via edges:
$$|S| = \sum_{(s,t)\in E} \frac{1}{\mathrm{deg}(s)}$$
and similarly for $T$.  Then argue that $|S|\leq|T|$.

For the second part, apply [Hall's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall's_marriage_theorem).  Every regular bipartite graph has a perfect matching.